# $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode() not working in observer for credit card payments

Tags: event-observer, payment, ee-1.14, ee-1.14.2.4

I'm trying to modify the payment block on the order detail page in backend. Therefore I've created an observer which is listening to following event:

```
payment_info_block_prepare_specific_information
```

Now, when I'm trying to get the payment code with

```
$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
$paymentmethod = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

I do get following error for credit card payments (Authorize.net) only:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCode()
```

Orders placed by using PayPal Express Checkout work though. Do I miss something? I appreciate any help.

Magento ver. 1.14.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a shorter and more direct way to the data you want. The method code is stored on the payment info instance (`sales_flat_order_payment`) as column `method`.

That means:

```
$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
$paymentmethod = $payment->getMethod();
```

That should give you the payment method code (as a string) in `$paymentmethod`.